# SAS nested macro, how to use varible outside macro

Tags: variables, macros, nested, sas

Hopefully can explain this clearly.   I'm using SAS 8.2 (It's what my company uses) and trying to get the variable name called &op_var_name that is created in the create_var macro.  This changes every time the run_loops macro runs.  Example,  it will create list_detail1, list_detail2 and list_detail3 based on the ds_split_list dataset.  I need to use these variables later in the code, I can't seem to get it work.  I have tried adding %global &op_var_name in the run_loops, and create_var macro.  The log shows the variable with data in the run_loop section, but then the log shows blank later in the code when the variable is referenced.

```
%macro create_var(ds_in=, item_to_list=, op_var_name=);

data &op_var_name;
set &ds_in end=eof;
length gen_list $30000.;
retain gen_list;
if not eof then do;
   gen_list=trim(left(gen_list))||"'"||trim(left(&item_to_list))||"'"||  ",";
end;
if eof then do;
   gen_list=trim(left(gen_list))||"'"||trim(left(&item_to_list))||"'";
   call symput("gen_name",trim(left(gen_list)));
   output;
end;
run;


%put &op_var_name=&gen_name ;


%mend create_var;

data _null_;
 set ds_split_list;
 call symput ('nobs', _n_);
 call symput ('ds_feed'||left(_n_),memname);
 call symput ('item_to_list', 'lotlabel');
 call symput ('op_var_name'||left(_n_), 'list_detail'||left(_n_));
run;


%macro run_loops;
  /* &nobs and all the "&&var&i" variables defined above */
     %do i = 1 %to &nobs;
        %create_var(ds_in=&&ds_feed&i, item_to_list=&&item_to_list, op_var_name=&&op_var_name&i);
     %end;
%mend run_loops;

%run_loops;


/* Later in the code is where I reference the variable created above. */

%get_oper(list=&list_detail1);
```

Thanks!

EDIT: I ended up using this option from Tom's responds.

Or you could make the variable global when it is created in the sub macro.

```
%global &op_var_name;
%let &op_var_name=&gen_name ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a typo and a logic error.  The typo is that your inner macro has a `%PUT` statement instead of a `%LET` statement.  So the only macro variable that is made is the one named `GEN_NAME` and not one named after the analysis variable.  So change it to this line.

```
%let &op_var_name=&gen_name ;
```

The logic problem you have is that your initial reference to the new macro variable is inside the inner macro, so by default it becomes local and disappears when the macro ends. You could simply define the macro variable first before calling the macro.

```
%let &&op_var_name&i=;
%create_var(ds_in=&&ds_feed&i, item_to_list=&&item_to_list, op_var_name=&&op_var_name&i);
```

Or you could make the variable global when it is created in the sub macro.

```
%global &op_var_name;
%let &op_var_name=&gen_name ;
```

You could even use `CALL SYMPUTX()` to do that and eliminate the extra GEN_NAME macro variable.

```
call symputx("&op_var_name",gen_list,'global');
```

Do you really need all of those individual datasets in addition to the macro variables?  Why not just make the macro variable directly from the input dataset without creating another dataset?

```
proc sql noprint ;
  select "'"||trim(left(&item_to_list))||"'"
    into :&op_var_name separated by ','
    from &ds_in
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: I updated my post, but forgot to say I'm using SAS 8.2.  That throws out the symputx option.  The %let option didn't work either unless I didn't something incorrectly.  The question I have where you have the %let before the %create_var macro, is what do I set that too?   The sql option I like, but would require more changes to the code I didn't post.

Comment: Even in 8.2 you should be able to declare the Macro-Vars with global scope. Add at the beginning of your macro: `%GLOBAL op_var_name ;`

Comment: Added `%GLOBAL` example to answer.

Comment: @Tony You probably need to bite the bullet and upgrade your version of SAS.  SAS 8.2 was released over 15 years ago.  http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/08/02/how-old-is-your-version-of-sas-release-dates-for-sas-software.html

Comment: @Tom I wish the company would upgrade there are so many things the new version has that I wouldn't have to work around in 8.2.  Thanks for you help Tom!

Answer (score 0):

Macro variable scope. Declare as global if you want to use outside of macro. Call symputx has a third parameter that specifies scope.